# Using removeClass to adjust css on div not working

Tags: jquery

I am passing the value from a dropdwon to then show and hide a seperate div and to also add/remove a class to the same element. The show/hide works fine but the new class added (mine) is added but not removed.

Does anyone know how to remove the class when div is hidden, using code below?

```
$(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".details-tcs").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
                $("." + optionValue).addClass("mine");

            } else{
                $(".details-tcs").hide();
                $(".details-tcs").removeClass("mine");
            }
        });
```

Here is what I get when I change the dropdown around.

```
<div class="details-tcs SC mine" style="display: none;">
stuff
</div>
<div class="details-tcs AI mine" style="display: block;">
stuff
</div>
<div class="details-tcs BB mine" style="display: none;">
stuff
</div>
```

It leaves the 'mine' showing once added.

The dropdown value is either SC, or AI or BB from -

```
jQuery("select").change(function()
```

Comment: When do you run this program snippet ? Can you share some more context(HTML structure and Javascript)

Comment: The problem is that you probably remove the class "mine" as global selector ".details-tcs" in the loop body. I can only guess without html.

Comment: Sorry I have added html

Comment: what is `$(this)` ?

Comment: sorry i added more code

Answer (score 0):

The **attribute** `value` is not updated on an element when its value changes; it serves only as **initial value**. That means if your `select` elements are initially empty, `$(this).attr("value");` gets you `""` (an empty string). When coerced to a Boolean, as in `if (optionValue)`, an empty string is evaluated to `false`. If it *does have* an initial value, that attribute is never going to change, so `$(this).attr("value");` will always return a non-empty string, which, when coerced to a Boolean as in `if (optionValue)`, evaluates to `true`.

You are probably looking for the **property** `value` instead:

```
var optionValue = $(this).prop("value");
```

Comment: tks so much for your help